# Converting a UK formatted string DateTime ("dd/MM/yyyy") to a valid DateTime where the culture may change

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, cultureinfo, tryparse

My application only receives strings in "dd/MM/yyyy" format and it has to convert these to a valid datetime which depends on the culture of the machine the application is running on (US, UK etc). If my application is running on a US culture machine the conversion from string to a valid datetime fails using the TryParseExact method as it is receiving a UK format string and trying to parse to a US string.

How can I parse a string which is in the UK format of "dd/MM/yyyy" to a valid DateTime which has a format depending on the culture info. E.g. to "MM/dd/yyyy if it is on a US machine? I am having more trouble than I thought I would have with this. Thank you

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string format = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

DateTime RequestFrom;
DateTime RequestTo;
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/12/2019", format, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out RequestFrom);
DateTime.TryParseExact("19/12/2019", format, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out RequestTo);
```

Comment: Set `format` to the UK format, not the current culture's format.

Comment: If the strings are always in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format then that's the format you want to use to parse the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 - You can use `ParseExact` by giving the input format

```
string inputdate = "01/12/2019";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(inputdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Method 2 - If you have many input formats, you can use `TryParseExact`

```
string inputdate = "01/12/2019";
DateTime dateTime = ParseDate(inputdate )

private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate)
{
    DateTime validDate;
    string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy" };
    var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        providedDate,
        formats,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out validDate);
    return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: If this is on a US machine the parse seems to fail due to a UK format and US culture

Comment: @Zeus7 Are you saying that on a US machine that your input strings are actually in the "MM/dd/yyyy" format?  Your question states that the input strings are always "dd/MM/yyyy".  Are you sure the issue isn't how you display the dates after they are parsed?

Comment: Sorry I am wrong here, the string which was in the test data was 31/11/2019 which is an invalid date anyway!